# I want that "whenever i click on Pie Chart Slice, it should pass values to another page". How can i achieve this using Lavacharts in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have tried to implement this but didn't found success. Please help me in implementation of this. Thanks in advance

**1. This is my Controller code.**

```
 public function dashboard()
 {
    $project2 = DB::select("SELECT sector, COUNT(id) AS T_PROJ`enter code here`
                            FROM project_tbl
                            GROUP BY sector
                            ORDER BY sector");

    $Users = Lava::DataTable();

    $Users->addStringColumn('Sector');
    $Users->addNumberColumn('Total Projects');

    foreach($project2 as $ROW_PIE)
    {        
        $Users->addRow([$ROW_PIE->sector,$ROW_PIE->T_PROJ]);
    }

    Lava::PieChart('sector_wise', $Users, [
        'title'  => 'Sector Wise Projects',
        'is3D'   => true,
        'width' => 450,
        'height' => 290,
        'pieSliceText' => 'value',
        'slices' => [
            ['offset' => 0.2],
            ['offset' => 0.3]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

**2. This is my View's code**

```
<div>
  <div id="sector_wise"></div>
  <?= Lava::render('PieChart', 'sector_wise', 'sector_wise') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you wrap it around `<a></a>` tags, and define your route there?

Comment: Actually i want to send the value of clicked pie slice to another page. so it needs something else. i tried to use events property but dont know how to properly use it.

Comment: You could define a full URL path to another page in `<a>` tags as well.

Comment: Yes i know this but how i will know about which pie slice is selected? i want values of that specific selected pie slice to send over to another page to show relevant details. Hope you got it what i am trying to want ???

Comment: I think I do now, every "pie" has multiple slices, and every slice should lead to different page?

Comment: Yes, every pie slice should lead to one page with contents of selected pie slice(e.g lable of pie slice), so that i can use those values to query relevant data.